# how can I know what is the necessary permission for my new codeigniter project?

Tags: php, codeigniter, apache2, php-5.3

I just installed apache2 and php5 on my ubuntu computer, Ive done it before on debian but now I have a weird error.

when I try to reach a page with my framework in CodeIgniter I get this error

```
[error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  require_once(/var/www/project/system/core/CodeIgniter.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/project/index.php on line 202, referer: localhost/

[error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/project/system/core/CodeIgniter.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php5-common') in /var/www/project/index.php on line 202, referer: localhost/
```

before that I have an error of not found on my **include_path**, so , I changed it on my **php.ini** and i changed it to  **:/usr/share/php5-common**

Still... I have NO idea what is the error...

I changed permissions on my /var/www folder and its like user:user

on the line of index.php I have this:

```
require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably your `$config['base_url']` is wrong.
Make sure its properly identifies the localhost or IP you are using to access localhost.
I mean if you are accessing local server or remote server using **http://[ipaddress]** then you have to define baseurl like that only.
in your case may be `**$config['base_url'] = http://127.0.0.1/codeigniter_project_name**`

Similarly that applies to database config also.

Comment: Thank you, in some part was that, but the main reason, the folders were under root user, and I had to change it for www-data